# Appending each directory and files by pandas

Tags: python, pandas, append

I'd stacked to append each file using pandas.

I have daily directory and each directory has same name file.

Here is example.

1. api.log,click.log,id.log are in 20150401 directory.
2. api.log,click.log,id.log are in 20150402 directory.
3. api.log,click.log,id.log are in 20150403 directory.
4. api.log,click.log,id.log are in 20150404 directory.

I wanna gather api.log into one dataframe.

```
import os
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd

dir_list = ['20150401','20150402','20150403','20150404']
counter = 0
var_box = pd.DataFrame()
for dir_date in dir_list:
    next_path = current_path+"/"+dir_date
    os.chdir(next_path)

    df = pd.read_csv('api.log',sep="\t",names=['date_time','param','oid','url'],na_values=['NULL'])    
    try:        
        if counter == 0:
            var_box2 = var_box.append(df)
            counter += 1
        else:
            var_box3= var_box2.append(df)
            counter += 1
    except Exception as e:
        print e.message
print(var_box3)
```

I've checked this result,but var_box3 doesn't have each api.log files.

Thanks for reading

Comment: where is counter declared? shouldn't it be declared and initialised to 0 outside the try except?

Comment: naming variables 1, 2, 3 etc. is a typical sign that you should be using a list type. Your code has other issues, but you should really learn about python iteration before trying to use a package like pandas. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's counter? Did you forget it in the for loop?

---

The main issue here is that append returns None:

```
var_box2 = var_box.append(df)
```

and None has no append method, so this will raise an AttributeError:

```
var_box3 = var_box2.append(df)
```

which is caught by your Exception, and ignored.

*Generally you want to avoid catching Exception as this includes any problem e.g. if you ctrl+C to end the process (this will be caught).*

---

I think what you want to do here, to make one frame from several, is concat:

```
pd.concat(var_box)
```